# undefined property when setting mask with processing js

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js

I'm using processingJS to put a mask on the image and output it

```
/* @pjs preload="mask.png"; */
PImage mask = loadImage('mask.png');
PImage img = loadImage(img);

image(img, 0,0); // works - outputs image
img.mask(mask);
image(img, 0,0); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
```

Comment: once again this was a security issue of canvas not being able to read pixels of remote image

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this works at all is slightly mystifying, because of the `PImage img = loadImage(img)` line: you've not declared `img` yet, but use it as argument for `loadImage` anyway =)

I would recommend first fixing the code so that you only use declared variables as function arguments (perhaps with a preload for `'image.png'` in addition to `'mask.png'` and loading that into your `img` variable) and then seeing if you're still having problems.